# How to use std::get as a global_fun of boost-multi-index container keys?

Tags: c++, tuples, boost-multi-index

I am using `boost::multi-index` container for a collection of tuples, and I would like to create an index on the first element of the tuple. Here is my solution by creating an wrapper function `getFirst` and pass it to the template parameter of the `multi_index_container` as the `global_fun`

This solution works, but I am wondering if it is possible to use `std::get` **directly**, without defining another wrapper function.

```
namespace {
    using my_tuple_t  = std::tuple<int, double>;

    int getFirst(my_tuple_t x) {
        return std::get<0>(x);
    }

    struct first {
    };

    using my_container = bmi::multi_index_container<
            my_tuple_t,
            bmi::indexed_by<
                    bmi::ordered_unique<
                            bmi::tag<struct first>,
                            bmi::global_fun<my_tuple_t, int, &getFirst>
                    >
            >
    >;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::get` directly, but what you get is more verbose than simply wrapping the thing as you've done:

```
using my_container = bmi::multi_index_container<
  my_tuple_t,
  bmi::indexed_by<
    bmi::ordered_unique<
      bmi::tag<struct first>,
      bmi::global_fun<const my_tuple_t&, const int&, &std::get<0, int, double>>
    >
  >
>;
```

The problem is that `std::get` is not a function but an overload set of function templates, and `global_fun` expects a concrete function pointer, so to get that you need to instantiate `std::get` with all its template arguments explicitly written down. Check for instance [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) for an explanation of the template parameters involved.